# runtime_error when calling boost test function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

Trying to run some tests through the use of the boost test library by using the following code:

```
int main(int arg, char *argv[])
{
    string help = "help";
#ifdef TESTING_CONSTANT

    TestingPeerClass testingClass;
    testingClass.test_method();

#else
    //rest of the codre
#endif
}
```

Which calls the following test function found in another class called testing.h :

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE mytest 

#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(TestingPeerClass)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(1 == 1);
}
```

when running the test a strange runtime error raises when it hits the BOOST_CHECK function.

[image]

I cant figure out why, any ideas? since when i built a new project it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you produce ans [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that exhibits that behavior?

Comment: BOOST_CHECK(1 == 1) produces that error

Comment: You do not need to have the first snippet of code, boost.test is doing properly the `main` and the call to the test body for you. Just getting rid of the entire file containing the `main` should help.